# Read a variable with multiple occurrences from a file using AWK

Tags: bash, file, awk

I want to get the value (usually a string) of var1 in a file my_file.dat and save this value to x.

I managed to do this using the following command:

```
x = `awk '$1 == "var1" {print $2}' my_file.dat`
```

It now turns out that there can be several occurrences of var1 in my_file.dat, e.g.:

```
Series1
var1 = temp/data/
Series2
var1 = lost/oldfiles/
```

My question is then how can I get only the value of the 'var1' which is located right after the line 'Series1', such that 'x' returns 'temp/data/'?

Comment: x = `awk '$1 == "var1" {print $2}' my_file.dat` is not a valid command. You may want to say `x=$(awk '...' file)`, without spaces around `=`.

Comment: `{print $NF; exit}` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample you posted all you need is:

```
x=$(awk 'prev=="Series1" {print $NF} {prev=$0}' file)
```

but more robustly:

```
x=$(awk '
    { name=value=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",name); sub(/[^=]+=[[:space]]*/,"",value) }
    (prev=="Series1") && (name=="var1") { print value }
    { prev=$0 }
' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a two state machine to solve the problem:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    state = 0;
}

{
    if( state == 0 )
    {
        if( index( $1, "Series" nseries ) )
        {
            state = 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( index( $1, "Series" ) > 0 )
        {
            exit
        }

        if( index( $1, "var1" ) > 0 )
        {
            idx = index( $0, "=" )
            str = substr( $0, idx + 1 )
            gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", str )
            print str
            exit
        }
    }
}

# eof #
```

Test file:

```
Series1
var1 = temp/data/

Series2
var1 = lost/oldfiles/

Series3
var1 = foo/bar/

Series4
var1 = alpha/betta/

Series5
var1 = /foo/this=bad

Series6
var1 = /foo/Series/
```

Reading `var1` from `Series1`:

```
x=$(awk -v nseries=1 -f solution.awk -- ./my_file.dat)
echo $x
temp/data/
```

Reading `var1` from `Series5`:

```
x=$(awk -v nseries=5 -f solution.awk -- ./my_file.dat)
echo $x
/foo/this=bad
```

Reading `var1` from `Series6`:

```
x=$(awk -v nseries=6 -f solution.awk -- ./my_file.dat)
echo $x
/foo/Series/
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: that will fail when the file name contains `=`, e.g. `tmp1 = /foo/this=bad` or `Series` or similar.